# Why doesn't setting the pixmap of a QLabel work?

Tags: qt, qpixmap

I've created a subclass of `QLabel` that I intend to use in a `QGraphicsView`. It serves as a movable "point" that one can click on and drag around the graphics view.

Creating the custom class and having it displayed in the graphics view hasn't been an issue; however, trying to get the custom `QLabel` to paint itself with the image I want isn't happening. The constructor for my custom `QLabel` class is like so:

```
TrackerPoint::TrackerPoint(QWidget *parent) :
    QLabel(parent)
{
    this->setFixedSize( 40, 40 );
    QPixmap pixmap( ":/images/target.png" );
    this->setPixmap( pixmap );
    this->setMask( pixmap.mask() );
}
```

I've ensured that the images directory exists in the working directory that the application is run from. If it is relevant at all, my QRC file is like so:

```
<RCC>
<qresource prefix="/images">
<file>images/target.png</file>
</qresource>
</RCC>
```

I've been trying to deal with this problem for days -- any ideas as to why the image isn't appearing would be lovely. (Does it have to do with the fact that I'm setting a pixmap in the constructor of the `QLabel`?)

Comment: Maybe you did override `paintEvent` of `QLabel` via `TrackerPoint::paintEvent` ?

Comment: The ctor usage should be fine. Although Subclassing shouldn't be necessary in most cases. Did you try to create a label outside the graphicsscene? Did you try QGraphicsPixmapItem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have:

```
<qresource prefix="/images">
<file>images/target.png</file>
</qresource>
```

I think that this will result in a double `images` in the resource path, i.e. `:/images/images/target.png`.  To fix that, either remove the `prefix="/images"` or put `alias="target.png"` in the `file` tag.

To make it clearer where the error is, you could write your code so that it uses `QPixmap::load`, since that can be checked for errors:

```
QPixmap pixmap;
if (!pixmap.load( ":/images/target.png" )) {
    qWarning("Failed to load images/target.png");
}
this->setPixmap( pixmap );
```

Or you could go even further and use `QImageReader` which can give detailed error messages.

Comment: Thank you much! That solved my problem. Also, tangentially, if I want to use PNG transparency into my QLabel, is there anything special I need to do?

Comment: No, you don't need to do anything special other than having the Qt PNG plugin.